# How can I back up my entire Windows 7 and restore it? If the bootmanager is on a different drive than where Windows 7 is installed?

Tags: windows-7-backup

How can I back up my entire Windows 7(system drive and everything which makes it boot) and restore it? If the bootmanager is on a different drive than where Windows 7 is installed?

Comment: You could backup the two disks using a third-party product such as [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html).

Comment: You could backup the two disks using the built in utility.  There is no need for a third party tool.  https://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/207414-backup-restore-across-two-drives.html

Comment: @harrymc Windows 7 is installed on a 120GB SSD and the bootmanager is on a 500GB HDD. I rather back up only the 120GB SSD, is there a way identify where the bootmanager and other partitions Windows 7 creates are located.

Comment: See [8 Free Tools to Backup and Restore the Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/5-free-tools-to-backup-and-restore-master-boot-record-mbr/).